# Error on curl for sample Spring OAuth2.0 server?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I am trying to setup a sample OAuth2.0 server using this guide.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/tree/master/tests/annotation

Following the instructions from the readme, I start the server with:

```
$ cd vanilla
$ mvn package
$ java -jar target/*.jar
```

However, when I run

> curl -H "Accept: application/json"
>   my-client-with-secret:secret@localhost:8080/oauth/token -d
>   grant_type=client_credentials{... "access_token":
>   "b561ff06-4259-466e-92d8-781db1a51901", ...}

I get

> Could not resolve host: access_token curl: (6) Could not resolve host:
>   b561ff06-4259-466e-92d8-781db1a51901,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>The error message is a big hint. You need to quote your arguments.</strike>

After reading [on github](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/tests/annotation/README.md), the command you must issue is

```
curl -H "Accept: application/json" my-client-with-secret:secret@localhost:8080/oauth/token -d grant_type=client_credentials
```

(usually when the line starts with `$` it's the command the next one(s) is/are the result)